# Netbeans Platform separator in action annotation

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm making a global actions toolbar, and I'd like to add a separator after some buttons, but when using separatorBefore and separatorAfter in @ActionReference annotation, nothing happens. I tryed several integer values, but none of them works.

```
// Add Action
@ActionID(
    category = "Gestion",
    id = "com.xxx.core.AddAction")
@ActionRegistration(
    iconBase = "com/xxx/core/resources/add_24.png",
    displayName = "#CTL_Add")
@ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/Gestion", position = 0100, separatorAfter = 0101)
@NbBundle.Messages("CTL_Add=Nuevo")
public static final String ADD_ACTION = "AddAction";
```

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
Charly

Answer (score 0):

Extend JSeperator and use it in your layer file.
[DevFaqJSeparatorInMainToolbar](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqJSeparatorInMainToolbar)